# Problem with website using QNetworkAccessManager Investing.com

Tags: c++, qt

I am trying to read automatically some information from investing.com using QNetworkAccessManager. I can read from other sites but this site gives some webmaster tools which I want to access.
https://www.investing.com/webmaster-tools/

I use this query which works in a browser.
Here is my request code

```
class InvestingAPI: public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT

    public:
       InvestingAPI();
       QueryTechnicals(QString Symbol, int TF1Minites);

    signals:
    //   void NewTechnicalSummary(int Timeframe, QString Symbol, QString Summary);
    private slots:
       void onData(QNetworkReply *reply);
    private:
      QNetworkAccessManager qnam ;

};

InvestingAPI::InvestingAPI()
{
```

connect(&qnam,SIGNAL(finished(QNetworkReply*)),this,SLOT(onData(QNetworkReply*));

connect(&qnam,SIGNAL(encrypted(QNetworkReply*)),this,SLOT(onData(QNetworkReply*))
);

```
}

InvestingAPI::QueryTechnicals(QString Symbol, int TF1Minites)
{
QString Query;
Query = "http://ssltsw.forexprostools.com/index.php?timeframe=300&lang=1&forex=1&commodities=8830,8836,8831,8849,8833,8862,8832&indices=175,166,172,27,179,170,174&stocks=334,345,346,347,348,349,350&tabs=1,2,3,4%22%20width=%22317%22%20height=%22467%22%3E%3C/iframe%3E%3Cdiv%20class=%22poweredBy%22%20style=%22font-family:arial,helvetica,sans-serif;%20direction:ltr;%22%3E%3Cspan%20style=%22font-size:%2011px;color:%20&selectedTabId=QBS_1";

QNetworkRequest Request;
Request.setSslConfiguration(QSslConfiguration::defaultConfiguration());
connect(&qnam,SIGNAL(finished(QNetworkReply*)),this,SLOT(onData(QNetworkReply*)));
Request.setUrl(QUrl(Query));

Request.setRawHeader("User-Agent", "MyOwnBrowser 1.0");
qnam.get(Request);
}
```

And I have event

```
void InvestingAPI::onData(QNetworkReply *reply){
    // find data type
    // decode and return data to caller
    if(reply->error() != QNetworkReply::NoError){
        qDebug() << "Error";
        qDebug() << reply->errorString();
    }
    QString  html =  QString::fromUtf8(reply->readAll());
    qDebug() << html;
    QString SubData;
}
```

I do not get an error but I get an empty string rather than the html response.

Please help as I have no idea why this is not working here but is working in the browser.

Comment: Have you checked the response of the browser with a network monitor? Probably your browser makes a redirect or sends some headers or cookies. The first step is to reproduce the behavior with Postman.

Comment: I tried that thank you it seemed to come back with the exact result I was hoping to get in my program which is an HTML page. No cookie

Comment: Did you compare the requests and responses using a network monitor like Wireshark?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default Qt Network does not handle redirects like other tools, so that is why you get an empty data (if you check the "Location" header you will see the redirected url). In this case it is to enable the redirection:

```
Request.setAttribute(QNetworkRequest::FollowRedirectsAttribute, true);
```

Comment: Thank you great idea. I Tried this fix but I now get Error Connection closed. Not sure why I don't get that error with the FollowRedirectsAttribute.

Comment: @TrumpFan I have tested it and I have not had that error, could you provide a [mre]. Where did you declare "qnam"?

Comment: Thanks you might be right and the problem is somewhere else. Also thank you for testing it. I get this message in wireshark part way through: 92010 705.488428 185.94.85.243 192.168.1.23 ICMP 82 Destination unreachable (Host administratively prohibited). I am running on windows and checked my firewall settings which allow everything for my program. Also on wireshark it seems to be reverting to http I added to my request this:  Request.setSslConfiguration(QSslConfiguration::defaultConfiguration()); but it is still only http.

Comment: @TrumpFan mmm, I use in linux where ssl is already linked so I handle https natively, I will analyze later in windows

Comment: @TrumpFan Please avoid putting code in the comments as they look horrible, instead edit your question

Comment: I have got the SSL libraries installed and it does initilise the SSL when it is called the first time.

Comment: @TrumpFan I have created a github action to do the test and I get the html correctly, project: https://github.com/eyllanesc/stackoverflow/tree/master/questions/63577032 execution: https://github.com/eyllanesc/stackoverflow/actions/runs/224685415

Comment: Thank you I got your project and it is working. I just need to integrate it into my project now. Very perfect answer.